# Getting Error for td : stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am new to selenium coding, and I have the  below code where I am fetching values from the  table it has multiple pages,
for 1st time, it reads all values from the  table and control move to the  next page, I m getting the  error stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
but when i m debugging the code, i m not getting any error for the  below code, when i run it throws an error and it shows an error at line where I have defined  tdCollection

Please guide me on this.

```
    var ReportCount = Convert.ToInt32(_driver.FindElement(By.Id("Reporter_TotalPages")).Text);

            for (int i = 0; i < ReportCount; i++)
            {
                IList<IWebElement> _records = (IList<IWebElement>)_driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[contains(@id,'ReportViewerControl')]//div//table//tbody//tr[position()>2]"));
                IList<IWebElement> tdCollection;
              
                for (int j = 0; j < _records.Count; j++)
                {
                   
                   tdCollection = _records[j].FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
                    
                    var Patientdemolist = new XPatientDemographicsList();
                    {
                        Patientdemolist.PatientID = tdCollection[0].Text;
                        Patientdemolist.LastName = tdCollection[1].Text;
                        Patientdemolist.FirstName = tdCollection[2].Text; 

                    };
                    PatientDemographicsList.Add(Patientdemolist);
                    tdCollection = null;
                }
                if (ReportCount - 1 > i)
                {
                    // For Next Page
                    _driver.FindElement(By.Id("Report_Next")).Click();
                } 
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adjusting your conditional to this.

```
 if (ReportCount - 1 > i)
{
    // For Next Page
    _driver.FindElement(By.Id("Report_Next")).Click();
    Thread.Sleep(5000)
}
```

Its possible you are getting a reference before the page has completed loading from the .Click() method.
If that works you can refine the tests to wait implictly/ use fluent waits instead of waiting for 5 seconds.
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/